# Alternative to building a large pivot query

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have 2 tables I am getting data from for a report (I am using generic tables for this example):

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(
DeptId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
DepartmentName varchar(20) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmpId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
FirstName varchar(20) NULL,
LastName varchar(30) NULL,
WorkStatus int NOT NULL,
DeptId int NOT NULL
 )


INSERT INTO Department (DepartmentName)
Values ('Finance'),
       ('Personnel'),
       ('Research'),
       ('Info Tech'),
       ('Production')

INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, WorkStatus, DeptId)
VALUES  ('Steve', 'Smith', 2, 3),
    ('Jim', 'Jones', 3, 1),
    ('Dave', 'Black', 1, 2),
    ('Nancy', 'White', 2, 4),
    ('Judith', 'North', 1, 5),
    ('Austin', 'West', 3, 5),
    ('Herbert', 'Livingston', 2, 5)
```

I need to create a report that will list the 'number of different work statuses by department', so Research has one person with workstatus 2 and so forth.  I would usually go at it with a pivot query, something like:

```
    SELECT DepartmentName, [1] as [Status 1],[2] as [Status 2],[3] as [Status 3]  FROM
    (SELECT    e.EmpId, d.DepartmentName, e.WorkStatus as WkStatus
          FROM  dbo.Employee e
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Department d
                            ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
          WHERE d.DeptId = 1

          UNION

     SELECT    e.EmpId, d.DepartmentName, e.WorkStatus as WkStatus
          FROM  dbo.Employee e
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Department d
                            ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
          WHERE d.DeptId = 2

          UNION

    SELECT    e.EmpId, d.DepartmentName, e.WorkStatus as WkStatus
          FROM  dbo.Employee e
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Department d
                            ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
          WHERE d.DeptId = 3
          UNION

    SELECT    e.EmpId, d.DepartmentName, e.WorkStatus as WkStatus
          FROM  dbo.Employee e
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Department d
                            ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
          WHERE d.DeptId = 4

          UNION

    SELECT    e.EmpId, d.DepartmentName, e.WorkStatus as WkStatus
          FROM  dbo.Employee e
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Department d
                            ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
          WHERE d.DeptId = 5
                ) UNIONqry
    PIVOT
    (count(EmpId) for WkStatus in ([1],[2],[3])) pvt
    Order by DepartmentName
```

However I am looking for a better method on this one because the actual query I am building has 120 'Departments' which would mean 120 unions.  The last one of these I did was only 18 'Departments' and the query took 2 seconds to run, so I am assuming 120 is going to take a bit.  So I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this, or if I should proceed with the above 'unioned pivot' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the count of the work status for each department, then you should be able to use PIVOT and no UNIONs:

```
select departmentname,
  [1] status1,
  [2] status2,
  [3] status3
from
(
  select d.departmentname, e.empid, e.workstatus
  from dbo.department d
  left join dbo.employee e
    on d.deptid = e.deptid
) d
pivot
(
  count(empid)
  for workstatus in ([1],[2],[3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d89d/7). I changed the JOIN to use a LEFT JOIN which will return all departments even if there is not a matching value in the `dbo.employees` table.

Comment: Both great answers, but this one seems to fit best with my situation.  Thank you both.  I would like to understand pivoting better, can you recommend a good source I can study?

Comment: I am curious as to how this query knows the different workstatus values and is therefore able to count all the 1s, 2s, etc.  For example, if the values for workstatus were chars instead of ints, say 'Full', 'Part', 'Mid' .  Would this query still work?

Comment: @teahou Yes if the work status was strings then it would still work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT d.DepartmentName,
       sum(case when e.WorkStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [1],
       sum(case when e.WorkStatus = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [2],
       sum(case when e.WorkStatus = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as [3]
FROM  dbo.Employee e INNER JOIN
      dbo.Department d
      ON e.DeptId = D.DeptId
group by d.DepartmentName;
```

You don't include sample results in the question, but I think this is what you are trying to do.  You can just add more `sum(case . . . )` clauses for the different work statuses.